# Finding location of the Concrete Class in a Service Locator Pattern

Tags: c#, design-patterns, service-locator

Is there an easy way to find the **concrete classes assembly location or name** when using the

**`Service Locator Pattern`** without running the containing solution?

Working in a library of significant size it is difficult to find the implementation which the Service Locator returns.

Is there an easy way I can find the types location given a Interface or by any other means (C#)?

For example, what is the location of the implementation that of `IOrder` that is returned?

```
_iOrder = ServiceLocator.GetService<IOrder>();
```

**Edit:** Can this be done outside of the containing solution, by using a console app for example?

Answer (score 1):

```
_iOrder = ServiceLocator.GetService<IOrder>();
string fullName = _iOrder.GetType().AssemblyQualifiedName;
```

Comment: I want to be able to do this without running the whole solution. How could this be done in a console app so it could be run independantly?

Comment: @ojhawkins It's straightforward - simply create a console project, add the references you need, prepare your container as needed so it contains the type you want to examine (so ServiceLocator.GetService<IOrder>() doesn't return null) and then run that console project.

Answer (score 1):

This should provide the desired details:

```
var fullName = _iOrder.GetType().FullName
```